# Angular: passing json - not appearing in frontend

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, get

I'm new to angular and I'm trying to pass my data to the frontend.
In the console it's answering with a "200 OK status (cached)" but it's not I looked through various of questions like this but I'm not able to get it done.

```
    .factory('caseFactory', function($http, $stateParams) {

 return{
    getCases : function() {
        return $http({
            url: 'assets/app/work/detail/' + $stateParams.caseID + '.json',
            method: 'get'
        })
    }
 }
})



.controller('workDetail', ['$scope', 'caseFactory',

function($scope, caseFactory) {

        $scope.case = [];
        caseFactory.getCases().success(function(data){
        $scope.case = data;
        console.log('well it works though');
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
        })
        .error(function(data) {
          console.log('sorry')
        });

}])
```

I'm not even sure about which expression is the right atm so I just tried
some and hoped it would work out.. at least once.

```
.state('detail', {
    url:'/detail/:caseID',
    templateUrl: 'assets/app/work/detail/detail-view.html',
    controller: 'workDetail',
    controllerAs: 'detail'

})


<div class="detailCover">
    <div class="detailCoverText">
        <h3>Headline{{ detail.title }}</h3>
        <div class="category">Kategorie{{detail.category}}</div>
        {{ detail.case.title }}
        {{ case.title }}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `controllerAs` syntax, so you should be referencing `this` instead of `$scope` in your view.  The best practice dictates that you should create a variable to represent `this` to avoid scoping issues.

```
function(caseFactory) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.case = [];

    caseFactory.getCases().success(function(data){
        vm.case = data;
        console.log('well it works though');
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    })
    .error(function(data) {
        console.log('sorry')
    });
}])
```

This allows you to call your template using `detail` to represent your controller's scope.

```
{{ detail.case[0].title }}
```

As for your caching, I suspect the template call is being cached, not the data call.

Since your data only shows with ng-repeat, it is an array.  You should index `case[0]`.

Comment: thank you for the fast answer! but it's still not showing up..
but it does if I use ng-repeat.

Comment: If it shows with ng-repeat, then it is an array.  Grab it via index.  Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use Chrome, and then Hamburger Menu, Developer Tools, Networking, and then Disable Cache, and try again